# terraform multiple vms, disks and sizes

Tags: terraform

I am trying to do the following:

Create multiple instances with multiple disks and sizes.

I have tried below code which works for multiple instances - one disk. However, what I'm trying to achieve is to create multiple instances with multiple disks and sizes.

```html
variables.tfvars

disks = [
    {
    "disk_name" = "disk1"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 5
    },
    {
    "disk_name" = "disk2"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 6
    }
]
   
instance_name = ["vm1", "vm2"]
```

```html
variables.tf

variable "disks" {
  type = any
  default = {}
}

variable "instance_name" {
  type = list
}
```

```html
main.tf

locals {
    vms = var.instance_name
    disks = var.disks
    vms_disks = [for k,v in zipmap(local.vms, local.disks): {
        vm = k
        disk_name = v.disk_name
        disk_type = v.disk_type
        size = v.size
    }]
}
```

Above code give output:

```html
Output:

[
  {
    "disk_name" = "disk1"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 5
    "vm" = "vm1"
  },
  {
    "disk_name" = "disk2"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 6
    "vm" = "vm2"
  },
]
```

Example of expected output although I'm not sure if the syntax is correct, but just to get the idea:

```html
Expected output:

[
   vm1 {
      "disk_name" = "disk1"
      "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
      "size" = 5
    },

  vm2 {
      "disk_name" = "disk1"
      "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
      "size" = 10
    },
    {
      "disk_name" = "disk2"
      "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
      "size" = 11
    },
]
```

Update:

When trying below variables.tfvars

```html
Updated variables.tfvars

disks = [{
    for_vm1 = [
        {
        "disk_name" = "disk1"
        "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
        "size" = 5
        }
    ],
    for_vm2 = [
        {
        "disk_name" = "disk01"
        "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
        "size" = 10
        },
        {
        "disk_name" = "disk02"
        "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
        "size" = 11
        }
    ]
}]
```

@Marcin suggestion

```html
locals {
    vms = var.instance_name
    disks = var.disks
    vms_disks = { for v in setproduct(local.vms, local.disks):
       v[0] => v[1]...
    }
}
```

I get output:

```html
{
  "vm1" = [
    {
      "for_vm1" = [
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk1"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 5
        },
      ]
      "for_vm2" = [
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk01"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 10
        },
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk02"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 11
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
  "vm2" = [
    {
      "for_vm1" = [
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk1"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 5
        },
      ]
      "for_vm2" = [
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk01"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 10
        },
        {
          "disk_name" = "disk02"
          "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
          "size" = 11
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your requirement here is similar to the one discussed in the docs as [Multi-level Nested Block Structures](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks#multi-level-nested-block-structures), assuming that the resource type you're using represents a whole VM and then has a nested block for each disk. For a fuller answer it would help to show an example of the actual resource block you've tried to write, rather than just the input variables it's derived from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that each vm should have two discs, as its not defined on what basis in your expected output, `vm1` ends up with one disk only. If so then you can use [setprodcut](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct) and `...`:

```
    vms_disks = { for v in setproduct(local.vms, local.disks):
       v[0] => v[1]...
    }
```

**UPDATE**

To account for different disks in different VMs, I would suggest changing `instance_name` and using it as follows:

```
variable "disks" {
  default = [
    {
    "disk_name" = "disk1"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 5
    },
    {
    "disk_name" = "disk2"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 6
    },
    {
    "disk_name" = "disk3"
    "disk_type" = "pd-standard"
    "size" = 7
    }
]
}

variable "instance_name" {
  default = {
    "vm1" = {
      "disks" = [0]
    },
    "vm2" = {
      "disks" = [0,1]
    },
    "vm3" = {
      "disks" = [0,2]
    }    
  }
}

locals {

    vms_disks = merge([
      for vm_name, vm_values in var.instance_name: {
        for disk_idx in vm_values.disks: 
          vm_name => var.disks[disk_idx]...
      }
    ]...)    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for your prompt reply. What I'm trying to achieve is vm1 should have one disk only, whereas for vm2 I expect 2 disks. Let's suppose there is vm3 as well that can have 1 or 3 disks. I have tried your suggestion and added code updates.

Comment: @ayuukja'ay You would have to modify your `instance_name`, to for example include disk numbers to use: `instance_name {vm1 = [0], vm2=[0,1], vm3=[0,2]}`. Later I can try to update the question to reflect that.