# terraform vcenter multiple vms, disks and sizes

Tags: terraform, vmware

Since I'm very new in terraform....
I have a similar situation like this
[terraform multiple vms, disks and sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034825/terraform-multiple-vms-disks-and-sizes)

Deploy multiple VMs from template and assign additional disks

So, here is my
terraform.tfvars

```
..
..
#VM
vm_template_name = "templates/rh8-template"
vm_guest_id = "rhel8_64Guest"
vm_ipv4_netmask  = "25"
vm_ipv4_gateway  = "192.168.50.3"
vm_dns_servers = ["172.17.0.2", "8.8.4.4"]
vm_disk_label  = "disk0"
vm_disk_size  = "20"
vm_disk_thin = "true"
vm_domain       = "cli-asset0338.devlab.local"
vm_firmware = "efi"

vms = {
  rh8_deploy_1 = { name = "rh8-dev1", vm_disk_size = 50, vm_vcpu = 2, vm_memory = 16384, vm_ip = "192.168.50.66"},
  rh8_deploy_2 = { name = "rh8-dev2", vm_disk_size = 60, vm_vcpu = 4, vm_memory = 32768, vm_ip = "192.168.50.77"},
```

...
and here is the

main.tf

```
..
..
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each              = var.vms

  datastore_id          = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  resource_pool_id      = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.compute_cluster.resource_pool_id
  guest_id              = var.vm_guest_id

  network_interface {
    network_id          = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
  }

  name                  = each.value.name
  num_cpus              = each.value.vm_vcpu
  memory                = each.value.vm_memory
  firmware              = var.vm_firmware
  cpu_hot_add_enabled      = "true"
  memory_hot_add_enabled   = "true"
  disk {
    label               = var.vm_disk_label
    size                = each.value.vm_disk_size
    thin_provisioned    = var.vm_disk_thin
  }
  clone {
    template_uuid       = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id
    customize {
      linux_options {
        host_name       = each.value.name
        domain          = var.vm_domain
    }
```

That is working flawless....
However what I failed to do; what if I want to clone machines and to add additional disks, something like ?

```
 vms = {
     rh8_deploy_1 = { name = "rh8-dev1", disk0_size = 50, disk1_size = 100, disk3_size = 100,0vm_vcpu = 2, vm_memory = 16384, vm_ip = "192.168.50.66"},
     rh8_deploy_2 = { name = "rh8-dev2", disk0_size = 60, disk1_size = 300, vm_vcpu = 4, vm_memory = 32768, vm_ip = "192.168.50.77"},
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?